# OpenLayers - Click on a panel triggers a map click but it should not

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery

I added a panel to a map that is contained inside an IFrame. Then I attach a click handler to the div of this panel with JQuery to toggle a control.

However, I notice that a click on the panel also trigger a map click event when it should not because another control handle the map click and both the panel and the map controls are triggered together.

```
var olmap = iframe.contentWindow.map // openlayers map inside the iframe
var i = olmap.getControlsByClass("Korem.Control.Info")[0] //map click control
var layerControl = olmap.getControlsByClass("Korem.Control.LightLayerControl")[0]
var customPanel = new iframe.contentWindow.OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
  id: "customPanel",
  autoActivate: true
});
olmap.addControl(customPanel)
iframeBody = $(iframe).contents().find("body");
var panel= iframeBody.find("#customPanel")
panel.css({"position":"absolute", "top":"0", "right":"0", "width":"auto", "height":"auto", "z-index":"1033"})
panel.append('<div id="clickLink" class="MenuItem1ItemInactive" style="cursor:pointer; padding:2px 5px; border:1px solid white; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;">Afficher les écoles</div>');
$(iframe).contents().find("#clickLink").click(function(){
    i.deactivate()
    if (layerControl.active == true) {
      layerControl.deactivate();
    } else {
      layerControl.activate();
    }
});
layerControl.events.on({deactivate : function(){
    i.activate();
  }
});
```

Is it normal that a click on a panel trigger a map click also? How could I prevent it?

Comment: Normally, no, click events are restricted to the map div itself. However, I think your issue is because your map is part of the iframe, which you then register a click event on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal, that OpenLayers registers click events to map instances when constructed. You can try to block them with the [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) method or prevent them with the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) method. If you use OpenLayers 2, you can try to unregister them manually, but you have to know which events you want to unregister (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637560/cant-unregister-click-event-in-openlayers). [OpenLayers 3 API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html) tells to use the above mentioned functions instead.